How to use Caddy as reverse proxy for Redis?
I am trying to run Redis (in the Docker container) behind a reverse proxy using Caddy.
Therefore I have configured the Caddy server like this:
example.com {
    reverse_proxy redis:6379
}

mapping the redis container to the URL.
When I expose the port 6379 directly from the container, everything works as expected. When I use the reverse proxy, the connection is blocked by Redis.
Do I need to configure Redis to allow using a reverse proxy? It might be a problem with the headers, but I am not sure, because the debug logs don't show anything helpful.
